# I want to know why my nodes aren't in my GameScene

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit, game-development

Below is my `didMove(toView:)` and the function I'm using to spawn my sprite nodes. Ignore the colored block portion of the code but I'm trying to get the balls to spawn and go up from the origin, I received no errors from the code but the ball isn't showing up in the view. I thank you very much if you are able to take the time out of your day to review my problem. Please ask questions if you need a clearer explanation of my problem.

Also please consider that the balls aren't in the scene initially and i want the added to the scene upon calling the function.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {


var greenBlock = SKSpriteNode ()
var redBlock = SKSpriteNode ()
var blueBlock = SKSpriteNode ()
var yellowBlock = SKSpriteNode ()

var greenBall = SKSpriteNode()
var redBall = SKSpriteNode ()

var ballSpeed: TimeInterval = 4

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    greenBlock = self.childNode(withName: "greenBlock") as! SKSpriteNode
    redBlock = self.childNode(withName: "redBlock") as! SKSpriteNode
    blueBlock = self.childNode(withName: "blueBlock") as! SKSpriteNode
    yellowBlock = self.childNode(withName: "yellowBlock") as! SKSpriteNode

    redBall.name = "redBall"
    greenBall.name = "greenBall"

    spawnRedAndGreen()




}

func spawnRedAndGreen () {

    redBall.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -1)
    redBall.zPosition = 4
    addChild(redBall)


    greenBall.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    greenBall.zPosition = 4
    addChild(greenBall)




    let upwardsMotion = SKAction.moveTo(y: 600, duration: ballSpeed)
    let redDelay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: 1, secondNum: 4)))
    let greenDelay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: 1, secondNum: 3)))

    let redSequence = SKAction.sequence([upwardsMotion, redDelay])
    let greenSequence = SKAction.sequence([upwardsMotion, greenDelay])



    redBall.run(redSequence)
    greenBall.run(greenSequence)

}
```

this is the function i used to generate the random numbers...

```
func randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: CGFloat, secondNum: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

    return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX) * abs(firstNum - secondNum) + min(firstNum, secondNum)

}
```

UPDATED CODE (note still doesnt work).

```
class GameScene: SKScene {


var greenBlock = SKSpriteNode ()
var redBlock = SKSpriteNode ()
var blueBlock = SKSpriteNode ()
var yellowBlock = SKSpriteNode ()

var greenBall = SKSpriteNode()
var redBall = SKSpriteNode ()

var ballSpeed: TimeInterval = 4

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    greenBlock = self.childNode(withName: "greenBlock") as! SKSpriteNode
    redBlock = self.childNode(withName: "redBlock") as! SKSpriteNode
    blueBlock = self.childNode(withName: "blueBlock") as! SKSpriteNode
    yellowBlock = self.childNode(withName: "yellowBlock") as! SKSpriteNode


    greenBall.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    greenBall.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    greenBall.zPosition = 4



    redBall.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    redBall.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    redBall.zPosition = 4

    spawnRedAndGreen()

}

func spawnRedAndGreen () {

    self.addChild(greenBall)
    self.addChild(redBall)


    let upwardsMotion = SKAction.moveTo(y: 1, duration: ballSpeed)
    let redDelay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: 1, secondNum: 4)))
    let greenDelay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: 1, secondNum: 3)))

    let redSequence = SKAction.sequence([upwardsMotion, redDelay])
    let greenSequence = SKAction.sequence([upwardsMotion, greenDelay])



    redBall.run(redSequence)
    greenBall.run(greenSequence)

}
```

I have also realized that the node count goes up by 2 everytime i call the function but it doesn't show up on the screen

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the size of your node or a texture/image to use otherwise it won't be visible. It would be also great if you specify the color.

```
redBall.size = CGSize(width: 0.1, height: 0.1)
redBall.color = .red
```

Also your action forces the node to move insanely fast (`y = 600` is too much, you can change it to `1`) so after the change above you will only see a blink.

Comment: hey thanks for your response but im using the action moveTo not any forces or impulses. other than that i appreciate your response extremely.

Comment: He is not talking about physics force, he is saying you are making the node move fast

Comment: sorry i didnt read your response correctly i have tried adding the position but it hasnt worked yet.

Comment: also do i have to add the properties (size, zposition, etc.) in the did move to view or the function i have created to spawn the balls

Comment: do redBall.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)` so you can see your ball

Comment: You need to do something to define what your ball is, you have no graphic/texture/size/shape/color/etc

Comment: the size of the balls are 30 by 30

Comment: so i should define the ball in the function or the DidMoveToView

Comment: Have you tried setting the color of your ball as I've answered? I've run your code in a playground and after setting color and size it worked.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED (thanks for everyones input i finally got it to work

```
class GameScene: SKScene {


var greenBlock = SKSpriteNode ()
var redBlock = SKSpriteNode ()
var blueBlock = SKSpriteNode ()
var yellowBlock = SKSpriteNode ()

var greenBall = SKSpriteNode()
var redBall = SKSpriteNode()

var ballSpeed: TimeInterval = 4

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    greenBlock = self.childNode(withName: "greenBlock") as! SKSpriteNode
    redBlock = self.childNode(withName: "redBlock") as! SKSpriteNode
    blueBlock = self.childNode(withName: "blueBlock") as! SKSpriteNode
    yellowBlock = self.childNode(withName: "yellowBlock") as! SKSpriteNode

    greenBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "greenBall")
    greenBall.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    greenBall.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    greenBall.zPosition = 4



    redBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redBall")
    redBall.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    redBall.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    redBall.zPosition = 4



    spawnRedAndGreen()

}

func spawnRedAndGreen () {




    let upwardsMotion = SKAction.moveTo(y: 1000, duration: ballSpeed)
    let redDelay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: 1, secondNum: 4)))
    let greenDelay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: 1, secondNum: 3)))

    let redSequence = SKAction.sequence([upwardsMotion, redDelay])
    let greenSequence = SKAction.sequence([upwardsMotion, greenDelay])


    self.addChild(redBall)

    redBall.run(redSequence)

    greenBall.run(greenSequence)

}
```